# Let’s Encrypt certbot cannot complete verification due to Nginx server config

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

For an application I need the following line in my `location` block:

```
rewrite ".*" /server.php break;
```

This causes certbot fail to verify the domain. To install the SSL cert I commented that line and certbot worked fine. Now, the issue is renewal is automated and will fail if I uncomment the line.

Is there a way to have a dedicated `location` just for Let's Encript's verification? If so, what?

Here is the full block with the problem line commented:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param USE_INSTANCE 'd1';
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    #rewrite ".*" /server.php break; 
}
```

If you wonder why I am not limiting the match pattern to `~ \.php$`, it is because the config belongs to my `api.host.com` endpoint which will only receive requests that need to be routed to a PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a separate `location` block for certbot.

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

(Note that I use the same document root for every virtual host, which is outside the normal document root, so certbot is never writing anything to the web sites' actual directories.)

Comment: After posting the question I tried `sudo certbot renew --dry-run` (with the line uncommented) and it worked. It may be because on renewal, there is no verification, or because with `--dry-run` the process is just *faked*. So, maybe there is no need for a change, but I'm not sure.